# xml parsing error in google map API

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have written a XML file with Javascript and PHP... and I'm having an error where it said `XML Parsing Error: not well-formed`. Can anyone help me please. I'm uploading the 2 files...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var customIcons = {
        criminal: {
          icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
          shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        },
        offender: {
          icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
          shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        }
      };

      function load() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.1666591, 57.503457),
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        downloadUrl("showsubject-script1.php", function(data) {
          var xml = data.responseXML;
          var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var subid      = markers[i].getAttribute("subid");
            var subaddress = markers[i].getAttribute("subaddress");
        var subremarks = markers[i].getAttribute("subremarks");
            var subtype    = markers[i].getAttribute("subtype");
            var point      = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("sublat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("sublng")));
            var html       = "<b>" + subid + "</b> <br/>" + subaddress + "</b> <br/>" + subremarks ;
            var icon       = customIcons[subtype] || {};
            var marker     = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: point,
              icon: icon.icon,
    });
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

  </script>
  </head>

  <body onLoad="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 1000px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the second file is:

```
<?php
require("db.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
  $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);  
  $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
  $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
  $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
  $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
  return $xmlStr; 
} 

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT id,addressfound,remarks, lat, lng,'criminal'  FROM criminalrecord");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $insert = mysql_query("insert into subjectrecord (subid,subaddress,subremarks,sublat,sublng,subtype) values ('$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]') ");
}

$query1 = mysql_query ("SELECT id,addressfound,remarks, lat, lng,'offender' subject FROM offenderrecord");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
{
  $insert1 = mysql_query("insert into subjectrecord (subid,subaddress,subremarks,sublat,sublng,subtype) values ('$row1[0]','$row1[1]','$row1[2]','$row1[3]','$row1[4]','$row1[5]') ");
}

$query2 = mysql_query ("SELECT subid,subaddress,subremarks,sublat,sublng,subtype FROM subjectrecord");

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '</markers>';

while ($row2 = @mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'subid="' .      parseToXML($row2['subid']) . '" ';
  echo 'subaddress="' . parseToXML($row2['subaddress']) . '" ';
  echo 'subremarks="' . parseToXML($row2['subremarks']) . '" ';
  echo 'sublat="' .                $row2['sublat'] . '" ';
  echo 'sublng="' .                $row2['sublng'] . '" ';
  echo 'subtype="' .               $row2['subtype'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Comment: Take your XML output, and put it through one of the XML validation tools available online.

Comment: there is no DTD for validation.. its about the google map API

Comment: You don't have to check it against a DTD, just for wellformed-ness ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CBroe suggested, your XML output is not well-formed. The problem seems to be the first `</markers>` which it should be an opening tag, i.e. `<markers>`.

Comment: Hey great its working now i just made this error </markers> .. it should be <markers>.. thnxx lotssss

Comment: sure.. its telling to have 15 reputation